# Segmentation fault with expect 5.43.0 with tclsh 8.4

Tags: ubuntu, tcl, expect

I am currently using expect 5.43.0 along with tclsh 8.4.

When i include the expect package i get segmentation fault.

my script contains

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
package require Itcl
package require Expect
```

How to fix this problem. Any suggestions will be helpful

Regards

Comment: Upgrade to Tcl 8.5 or 8.6; 8.4 is no longer supported. Or at least say exactly which patchlevel — `info patchlevel` — of 8.4 you're talking about; it covers over 10 years of versions…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was with tclsh8.4. I changed tclsh to previous version i.e tclsh8.3 and no segmentation error is found. Dont know why. Hope it helps

Comment: What version of what?